# Run a deamon loop without eating all the CPU (Perl)

Tags: perl, events, daemon, infinite-loop

I have the following code:

```
use Proc::Daemon;

Proc::Daemon::Init;
my $continue = 1;
$SIG{TERM} = sub { $continue = 0 };

while ($continue) {
     ##DO THINGS
}
```

I noticed that this script is using 7% CPU.  I believe it is because of the infinite loop.  I believe there is a way to make infinite loops not use much CPU (this is how event loops works).  How would I make this not use a lot of CPU (I suppose I could sleep, but i'm wondering if there is a better way).

The "things" that I do are very simple in nature.  Check if timers are expired or flags are set.  If they are, take an action.

Answer (score 4):

The `select` function allows you to have sub-second sleeps. e.g.:

```
# sleep for 100ms (0.1 seconds)
select( undef, undef, undef, 0.1 );
```

**Update**:

Event loops *typically* centre around a `select` call. The `select()` function tells the operating system to put your process to sleep until one of a list of filehandles has something interesting happen ("data available to read", "buffer available to write", or "filehandle in error").

The three parameters you provide to `select()` are *filehandles_to_read*, *filehandles_to_write*, *filehandles_to_monitor_for_error*. The last parameter is the maximum amount of time you're willing to wait for (the *timeout* value).

When you call `select( undef, undef, undef, 0.1 )` you're not asking the operating system to wake up on any filehandles at all, but the timeout value is still valid and wakes up the program after this period.

Comment: How do event loops do it without sleeping?

Comment: @johndoe updated answer for you. Please do some reading about the `select()` function call.

Answer (score 2):

See http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html and search for /nice/.

> **nice**
>
> This is similar to the C function nice() , for changing the scheduling
>   preference of the current process. Positive arguments mean more polite
>   process, negative values more needy process. Normal user processes can
>   only be more polite.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX;

POSIX::nice( 19 );
```